How to delete files locally but keep them in the remote repository
Is there any way to delete the files just from my local machine without deleting those from the
remote repository?
I want to clear the directories and files that I no longer need from my file explorer.
I am a beginner to git. So help me out.
I tried using the following method. But it didn't work out.
git rm --cached -r directory
git commit -m "Removed files from local tracking"
git push origin main

This deleted the files from my remote repo. But kept them on the local machine.

Do you mean you want to delete the entire project locally, or just specific files from it?

I don't know what you mean, but you can simply delete the files (AFTER ADDING to git, pushing the changes to remote, of course) and then just ignore afterwards by adding them to .gitignore file.

Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64480064/delete-files-from-local-not-remote

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

So you want to have some local changes just for you while working, that you do not want to push to the remote? That is what temporary commits are used for. If you want to keep the temporary commits after your delivery move them to a separate branch.

You want to use git sparse-checkout. Check git help sparse-checkout. I think an explanation is worth it if you are a newcomer to git.
It's not like you can post whatever you want in a remote.... You push branches (which are just pointers to commits) and they include all commits that make up the history of the tip of the branch.... So, you really do not just push files or directories, what you push are commits, whatever they include.... So, if in your local you remove stuff and you commit the removal, it becomes history of the branch.... And if you push it somewhere, well, it will be removed on those commits you are pushing.... There's no way you can push just a part of a commit.
What you want is a different mechanism: you want stuff to remain there but you only want to see on your work tree a subset of the content of the project. That is what sparse-checkout is for.
